Proving positivity of a complex function Involving derivatives of the incomplete gamma function
I am trying to prove that the following function is always positive:
$
        f(x) = 2 \gamma'' |x|^2 (1 - \gamma) + 6 \gamma'^2 |x|^2 - 8 \gamma' |x| (1 - \gamma) + 6 (1 - \gamma)^2 + \gamma'' |x|^4 (1 - \gamma)^2 + 2 \gamma'^2 |x|^4 (1 - \gamma)        
$
where:

$\gamma$ is a regularized lower incomplete gamma function which is given by

$$ \gamma  = \gamma \left(m, \frac{m}{\Omega} |x|^2 \right)=\frac{\int^{ \frac{m}{\Omega} |x|^2   }_{0} t^{m-1}e^{-t}dt  }{ \int^{ \infty   }_{0} t^{m-1}e^{-t}dt }.$$

$\gamma'$ is a first derivative of $\gamma$ which is given by

$$ 
 \gamma' = \frac{ \partial \gamma }{ \partial |x| } = \frac{ \partial \gamma\left(m, \frac{m}{\Omega} |x|^2 \right)}{ \partial |x| }.
$$

$\gamma''$ is a second derivative of $\gamma$ which is given by

$$
 \gamma'' = \frac{ \partial \gamma' }{ \partial |x| } = \frac{ \partial^2 \gamma\left(m, \frac{m}{\Omega} |x|^2 \right)}{ \partial |x|^2 } .
$$
Is there anyone who can help prove that $f(x)$ is always positive?
